# keep hard link connection after erasing a file

Tags: linux, bash, hardlink

I try to achieve something that I imagined very simple, but which is finally harder than expected.

I have a folder : `source/`. I have a second one : `target/`. I create a file `test.jar` in my first folder. Then, I want this file to appear and be executable in my second folder. I see 3 options :

- manually copy/paste my file. It works but... I don't want to do it each time I update my file.
- symbolic link. It works, but if I execute the jar file, the context is `source/` and not `target/` like I would like.
- hard link. That's exactly what I need, but the issue is that `test.jar` is not modified, but generated. This means that after erasing `source/test.jar`, `target.test.jar` still references the old file... Is it possible to force the 2 files to have always the same value ?

Thanks for your help !

**EDIT :** For now, I solved the problem by adding a line to copy my file from source/ to target/ inside a script that I will execute anyway after generating the jar. I think that what I wanted to do is actually impossible. It would need a new kind of linking which links the content of 2 files given their pathname and not their inode...

Comment: Depending on your environment, you can setup a build task that copies the (generated?) `.jar` for you. It will increase portability, since Windows doesn't support symlinks like Unix does.

Comment: >>"I don't want to do it each time I update my file." Check if [`inotifywait`](http://man.cx/inotifywait) or [`rsync`](http://man.cx/rsync) can help you.

Comment: I checked inotifywait and rsync. I'm sorry, I don't see exactly how I should use it to solve my problem. I think that the comment of @rr suggests the best approach for my case. I'm using Maven2. I will try, but I don't know yet how to achieve this. I will make some research and come back.

Comment: Ok. As I need this only for myself, I don't want to modify the pom. Is there a way with Maven to execute a build task only on my computer ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a soft link of the file. Create a soft link of the entire folder.

Something like

```
ln -s {whatever path}/source/ {whatever path}/target
```

Then the folder target/ is a folder-link to the first folder and context should be the same.

You can also try using git (locally) and checkout source/ to folder target.

Comment: This assumes there is *no* difference between `source` and `target` aside from their names.

Comment: Yes, as guest by chapner, the two folders are different. But thanks for your suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating an executable shell script named `test.jar` in the `target` directory and make it call the `path/source/test.jar` passing forwarding all the parameters. Something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
path/source/test.jar "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It could be a good idea, but I'd rather the jar file to be physically present in the folder. This way, if I want to copy, move, compress... the whole folder, I can do it very easily.

Comment: Then I guess you need to have a hard copy in the directory and make sure updates to source/test.jar are reflected in target dir... modifying the build procedure to ensure this is your best choice then